# Replace all occurrences in a string with values form a hash-map

Tags: clojure

I have a string which contains BB codes, something like `[img="image1"]something[/img]`. 
And I have a hash-map looking like this:

```
{:image1 "real_file_name.jpg"}
```

which contains the real image paths. I want to replace all `[img="XXX"]YYY[/img]` with `<img src="real_path">.....</img>`

So I need to find all `[img=...]` tags and replace with them with the corresponding values from the hash-map.

I know how to do this in the Java and similar languages. How can I do this in Clojure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would do it exactly like in any other language: iteratively find all the needed image structures with regexp, capturing necessary parts of every image, and then replace it with new string (replacing the captured image id with the corresponding value from the map):

you could use `clojure.string/replace` with regexp and replacement function like this:

```
user> (require '[clojure.string :as s])
nil

user> (def input "[img=\"image1\"]something[/img] [img=\"image2\"]something[/img]")
#'user/input

user> (def paths {:image1 "real/path1" :image2 "real/path2"})
#'user/paths

user> (s/replace input #"\[img=\"(.+?)\"\](.*?)\[/img\]"
                 (fn [[_ img-id content]]
                   (str "<img src=\"" (paths (keyword img-id)) "\">"
                        content "</img>")))
"<img src=\"real/path1\">something</img> <img src=\"real/path2\">something</img>"
```

Comment: what's the `keyword`?

Comment: `keyword` is a function, that converts string to a keyword: `(keyword "some-value")` => `:some-value`. Since you matches are strings and map keys are keywords, you should turn your match into keyword in order to look it up in a map